# How do you share projects on code.google.com with multiple repos?

Tags: open-source, project-management, google-code, code-sharing

I had difficulty in finding a single page or a url to point to someone for all the repos you own on code.google.com.

Does anyone know how? Do I need to do anything to create a page of something like what I get on bitbucket and github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if you click on the profile link in the upper left you get taken to a list of everything you're involved in.

**EDIT** : Old link removed.

Comment: thanks yes this will do for now ...phew why is google so cryptic of UI than others ....

Comment: Sorry that was so cryptic, I just revisited the question.  It looks like you can just click on the profile link in the upper right.

Comment: hey nothig to be sorry about i said it was G! who hid it not you..